# Запуск сервисов при старте системы (Ubuntu)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, systemd

Добрый день! При старте системы у меня запускаются некоторые сервисы (zookeeper, apache-cassandra, apache-storm, kafka). Вопрос следующего характера: как сделать так, чтобы эти сервисы запускались в необходимом для меня порядке? Почитал насчет chkconfig, rc.d и прочее, но так и не понял как это делается.

Comment: поставить их в зависимости друг к дружке

Comment: Если не составит труда, можно более подробно? Я впервые пытаюсь это сделать и все тщетно.

Comment: Вначале читаете это https://habrahabr.ru/company/centosadmin/blog/255845/ , потом открываете нужные файлы и пишете что то вида `After=syslog.target`

Comment: Благодарю вас за ответ!

Answer (score -2):

Для того чтобы сделать свою программу сервисом в Linux с использованием update-rc.d, достаточно выполнить следующее:

1. создать скрипт для управления жизненным циклом программы;
2. назначить необходимые права на файл;
3. зарегистрировать созданный скрипт как сервис;
4. разрешить автозапуск сервиса.

uzon-api.sh – скрипты для запуска|остановки в командной оболочке shell в Linux (управление жизненным циклом), уже созданы. Осталось только скопировать файл по адресу директорию /etc/init.d/ с названием uzon-api 
Назначение прав: Здесь все просто, чтобы скрипт смог выполняться, нужно дать необходимые права для данного файла. Это делается следующей командой:

```
chmod +x /etc/init.d/uzon-api
```

Регистрация скрипта как сервиса. Чтобы операционная система узнала о существовании нашего сервиса, потребуется его зарегистрировать. Для этого выполним команду:
update-rc.d uzon-api defaults
Разрешить автозагрузку. Теперь наш сервис известен операционной системе, и с ним уже можно работать, например, запускать или останавливать:

```
service uzon-api start
service uzon-api stop
```

Но, по умолчанию, после перезагрузки операционной системы, наша программа не будет работать. Для включения автозагрузки сервиса потребуется вызвать update-rc.d со следующими параметрами:

```
update-rc.d uzon-api enable
```

После этого, наш сервис полностью готов к работе.

В сервисе приритеты

```
# Required-Start:   99           запуск в последнюю очередь
# Required-Stop:    01           остановка в первую очередь
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5     вот это и есть приоритететы 
# Default-Stop:      1 0 6       вот это и есть приоритететы
```

о них стоит почитать отдельно

Создание «Демона» службы для программ на Java

```
#!/bin/sh
### BEGIN INIT INFO
# Provides:          uzon-api
# Required-Start:   99 запуск в последнюю очередь
# Required-Stop:    01 остановка в первую очередь
# Default-Start:     2 3 4 5     вот это и есть приоритететы 
# Default-Stop:      1 0 6       вот это и есть приоритететы
# Short-Description: ...
# Description: ...
### END INIT INFO

SERVICE_NAME=uzon-api
PATH_TO_JAR=/home/prog1/uzon-api-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar
PID_PATH_NAME=/tmp/uzon-api-pid
case $1 in
    start)
        echo "Starting $SERVICE_NAME ..."
        if [ ! -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            nohup /usr/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/prog/uzon-api-gc.log -jar /home/prog/uzon-api-server-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.jar >/home/prog/uzon-api.out 2>&1 &
            echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is already running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    stop)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stoping ..."
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ..."
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
    restart)
        if [ -f $PID_PATH_NAME ]; then
            PID=$(cat $PID_PATH_NAME);
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopping ...";
            kill $PID;
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME stopped ...";
            rm $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME starting ..."
            nohup /usr/bin/java -Xms2048m -Xmx2048m -XX:+PrintGCDetails -XX:+PrintGCDateStamps -verbose:gc -Xloggc:/home/prog1/uzonapigc.log -jar $PATH_TO_JAR >/dev/null 2>&1 &
            echo $! > $PID_PATH_NAME
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME started ..."
        else
            echo "$SERVICE_NAME is not running ..."
        fi
    ;;
esac
```

Comment: Автору нужно systemd

Comment: Ответ не релевантен вопросу